# Windows Firewall Block Inbound External IP

Tags: windows-7, windows, firewall, ip

I am trying to block 1 ip address from connecting to my computer. However I am confused by this screen: [image]

If the rule is set to block ip, but I cannot get a way to allow local ips. Is there a way to chose under "which local Ip addresses does this rule apply to" and chose none?

Comment: Anything that is not explicitly blocked is permitted with a block rule.  Blocking a single IP means only that IP will be blocked.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Im just confused by the phrase "Any IP Address". If the rule is for blocking, does the "Any IP address" under the local ip section mean ALL ips or no ips?

Answer (score 1):

When thinking about firewall rules, you always consider the rule as a whole, not its parts.

So in the above, we are saying

```
All Local IP addresses
```

AND

```
Remote Address 1.1.1.1
```

So to translate into English, "If the remote address is 1.1.1.1 and the local address is any IP, then block, otherwise permit."

So the consequence is that if the remote address is not 1.1.1.1 then this rule will not be matched, and so not block.   Any address that is not 1.1.1.1 will be implicitly permitted.

Comment: So how would I be able to allow any local ip and block only 1.1.1.1?

Comment: @agovizer That seems to be the same as my sentence above, have I misunderstood?